# Importing .net dll to Delphi 6 loses information

Tags: delphi, import, delphi-6, typelib

I have a .net dll which I could import to Delphi 6. But it loses some information.

I have a demo application in VB.net to use this dll which shows 2 interfaces called
`IRedeemTransactionItemBundle` and `ITransactionItemBundle`. In Visual Studio 2008 I could see that `ITransactionItemBundle` is the base type of `IRedeemTransactionItemBundle`. So when I declare a variable of type `IRedeemTransactionItemBundle`, I could access all properties of both interfaces.

But when I import the dll to Delphi 6, I could see both `IRedeemTransactionItemBundle` and `ITransactionItemBundle` declaration part. But there is no information that shows `ITransactionItemBundle` is the base type of `IRedeemTransactionItemBundle`. Also when I declare a variable of type `IRedeemTransactionItemBundle` in Delphi, I am not able to access properties of `ITransactionItemBundle` (the base type).

When I tried to register the library in tlb editor by setting the base type of `IRedeemTransactionItemBundle` to `ITransactionItemBundle`, I am getting the error: “Parent Interface already has a member with id:1610743808”. I could see properties of both interfaces have same ID in the tlb editor.

I tried to import the same dll using Delphi 7 also. But no help.

Is that a problem with Delphi? Have any of you experienced such a problem in importing kindly give me some thoughts?

Comment: How do you export this? Through COM? Please show us the header of the C# class declaration. How do you import it? Type Library Editor? Please show us the header of the imported Pascal bit.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to make COM visible wrapper for the DLL in C# or VB.NET which will import necessary functionality in the way Delphi can interact with correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using COM interop, you can do an [unmanaged export](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8013047/744588). Simply put, you need a new specific version of the .net dll.

Please head to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8431313/744588) for details of the technique using Delphi.